Are WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1" and SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true compatible options for a ZipDeploy Azure App Service Python WebApp on linux?
Are WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE="1" and SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true compatible options for a ZipDeploy Azure App Service Python WebApp on linux?
Also, my webapp is using gunicorn, if that matters.
When I deploy my python webapp as a zipfile, which includes my python files and a requirements.txt (but no venv). Ex command:
az webapp deploy --resource-group "$resource_group_name" --name "$app_name" --type "zip" --src-path "backend.zip"
My assumption is that my webapp will be built by Oryx and then Kudu will upload the package, a zip now including the venv, to /home/data/SitePackages with a packagename.txt in the same directory.
Then it will run it by mounting the package in /home/site/wwwroot.

They are NOT compatible, and here are my findings.
TLDR; If SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 the deployment will ultimately not include a venv and you will have ModuleNotFoundErrors.
Maybe this is a bug or poorly designed/documented solution. IMO, the deployment should fail if this config is given during deployment.
It appears that SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true is ignored/overridden if WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1. However, I haven't found any documentation stating this is expected behavior.
Why did I try it? Look at all these documented benefits WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1, which I thought would complement my SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true:


Eliminates file lock conflicts between deployment and runtime.
Ensures only full-deployed apps are running at any time.
Can be deployed to a production app (with restart).
Improves the performance of Azure Resource Manager deployments.
May reduce cold-start times, particularly for JavaScript functions with large npm package trees.


References:
I think these are the official documentation for WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE pertaining to App Services in general, so applicable to Web Apps.
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#deployment

WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE  Set to 1 to run the app from a local ZIP
package, or set to the URL of an external URL to run the app from a
remote ZIP package. For more information, see Run your app in Azure
App Service directly from a ZIP package.


Run your app in Azure App Service directly from a ZIP package

Official docs pertaining to Azure Functions (not my scenario):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings
https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84

Here is another confusing doc:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE-and-WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING-Best-Practices

If you are deploying the Python application to Linux Azure App Service, add the setting named SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT and set the value to true or 1, it triggers an Oryx build during deployment. WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 is not required for Linux App Service.
When you deploy a ZIP package, App Service unpacks its contents in the path home\site\wwwroot  for Windows,  /home/site/wwwroot  for Linux.

By default, the deployment engine assumes that a ZIP package is ready to run & doesn't run any build automation.

To enable the remote build automation, set the SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT application setting. It controls the build behavior and allows the project to build remotely during deployment.
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1
This setting is used when deploying the app to Windows App Service. t uploads the package to  d:\home\data\SitePackages  folder automatically.

I have Zip deployed the python application to Linux Azure App Service using the command:
az webapp deploy --resource-group "<rgname>" --name "<appname>" --type "zip" --src-
path "<projectname.zip>"



Added SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true in the application settings of the Web app.

This setting helps to automate the build:




Added gunicorn command as the startup command:

gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 --chdir appname app:app

Response:

References:
Configure Linux Python apps - Azure App Service

Thank you for your time, but the statement "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 is not required for Linux App Service." is misleading.  It is actually required for it to not be present or set to 0. Otherwise, you will have unexpected results.  See my answer.
